# Is there a way to change the background of a div when text is entered into an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code below and i want every time someone enter/type text inside the input field, force the background of the div with class "target_bg" to change its color from red(default) to green.

```
<div class="target_bg"></div>
<input placeholder="Search for Restaurants..." 
class="search_field" name="" type="text">
```

I searched a lot for a solution but i found only how to change the background of the input field itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html catch event when user is typing into a text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828450/html-catch-event-when-user-is-typing-into-a-text-input)

Comment: @Designer any news about this question?

Answer (score 0):

if using jquery:

```
$('.search_field').on('input', function() {
   $('.target-bg').css('background-color','green');
});
```

Comment: Is there any simple way to turn the div's background to its default color again when the field is empty?? eg if i delete the text of the field..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using plain javascript

```js
var bgElement = document.querySelector('.target_bg');
var input = document.querySelector('.search_field');

input.oninput = function() { bgElement.style.background = 'green'; };
```

```css
.target_bg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="target_bg"></div>
<input placeholder="Search for Restaurants..." class="search_field" name="" type="text">
```