# Counting sum of input values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have problem with my script

i want to count all and sum entered values automatically, instead clicking a side or part in window to bring results

like if i enter 1 and next input i enter 1 automatically show total, than clicking apart of window to show results

also i want to display total sum with currency word like  20 usd

```html
<head>
  <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="windows-1252">

</head>

<body>

  <form id="lines-form-1">
    <input type="number" name="i1">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="i2">
    <br>

  </form>
  <div id="tot-qty">usd</div>

  <script>
    $('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function() {
      var tot = 0;
      $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function() {
        tot += Number($(this).val());
      });
      $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Use `keyup` instead of `change`

Comment: You can flag it as a duplicate of this: [html catch event when user is typing into a text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828450)

Comment: thanks adiga it works with keyup, but the problem is usd, when i type it disappear, i want to show usd after counting all total like 20 usd

Comment: You can either add that when updating the text: `$('#tot-qty').text(tot + ' usd')`. OR you can put the `usd` outside of your `div` or `span` so that it doesn't get replaced: `<span id="tot-qty"></span> usd`.

Comment: thanks adiga it works